# Thrust to STL copy doesn't work as intended

Tags: c++, vector, stl, cuda, thrust

I'm not sure how `thrust::copy` to STL vector actually works.
When I do the following, it gives me expected result:

```
struct TestOperation
{
    TestOperation(){}

    __host__ __device__
   CustomPoint operator()(const CustomPoint& point)
   {
       CustomPoint pt;
       pt.x = point.x * 2;
       pt.y = point.y * 2;
       pt.z = point.z;
       return pt;
   }
};
void CudaLoader::TestLoader(std::vector<CustomPoint>& customPoints) //Host vector reference
    {
       thrust::device_vector<CustomPoint> devicePoints(customPoints.begin(), customPoints.end());
       thrust::device_vector<CustomPoint> output;
       output.reserve(devicePoints.size());
       thrust::transform(devicePoints.begin(), devicePoints.end(), output.begin(), TestOperation());
       for (int i = 0; i < customPoints.size(); i++)
       {
           customPoints[i] = output[i];
       }
    }
```

But looping trough all the elements especially when there are many of them doesn't seem optimal to me so I wanted to use `copy`. But when I try to do:

```
thrust::copy(output.begin(), output.end(), customPoints.begin());
```

instead of the loop, then I don't get expected result - host stl vector which reference was given as parameter remains unchanged. In addition, `output.size()` returns 0, but I see that storage size is correct. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that `customPoints.size() == output.size()`?

Comment: I was sure, but since you mention it - I'm not. I just assumed that creating device vector based on existing vector will result in vector of same size, but if it doesn't work like that then you would be right and these sizes wouldn't match.

Comment: (I'm mostly worried about whether you use `copy` correctly.)

Comment: I've just checked it, when I try to use `int size = output.size()` it gives me 0, eventough when I loop trough elements, as in the code provided, it works, so the data is present. I don't think I can explain why it works like that.

Comment: I've just noticed, output vector has `m_size = 0`, but `m_size` of a storage is equal to the number of points in the vector. I'm not sure why is that, but this could be the reason why copy doesn't work I believe? How should I use copy correctly then?

Comment: Don't use `reserve` for the output vector in your loader function. Use `resize`. `reserve` doesn't change the size of the vector, just the guaranteed minimum space reservation

Comment: Read the documentation for `copy`: The output iterator must point to a **valid range**. (Maybe you meant to use `std::back_inserter(customPoints)`, though.)

Comment: Would you mind if I edited the question to be more concise?

Comment: I don't mind at all, please do!

Comment: Done. Feel free to roll back if you think this strays too far from the original point.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Your edit pretty much invalidates all the code in my answer..... Also removes the very subtle reason why the original code (without thrust::copy) actually worked in the first place

Comment: I think the code should actually reffer to thrust so it matches accepted answer don't you think? There is some usefull info about transform not changing the size and why this code did not produce any error in first place. I will reprhase the question to simplify it in a minute.

Comment: @talonmies: The original code *doesn't* work in any sense you should feel comfortable with :-S ... but feel free to roll back.

Comment: How do you guys feel about the current state of the question?

Comment: (For what it's worth, I think your confusion has nothing to do with Thrust of Cuda, and the restricting the minimal example to pure standard library containers would address it just as well but be far more useful to others who are similarly confused. But it's your question :-) .)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is this:

```
   thrust::device_vector<CustomPoint> output;
   output.reserve(devicePoints.size());
```

`reserve` only changes the guaranteed minimum storage allocation for the vector. It doesn't change its *size*. In the code above `output.size()` is still 0. Also note that `thrust::transform` doesn't alter the size of the output vector. As long as there is enough valid memory to hold the output of the transformation, no illegal memory access error will be produced by the thrust closure kernel which performs the transform operation.

Do this instead:

```
   thrust::device_vector<CustomPoint> output;
   output.resize(devicePoints.size());
   thrust::transform(devicePoints.begin(), devicePoints.end(), output.begin(), TestOperation());
```

Then

```
thrust::copy(output.begin(), output.end(), customPoints.begin());
```

will work as expected because `output` has a non-zero size.

Comment: I'm extremely uncomfortable with the assertion that "as long as ... no error will be produced". That's very misleading. The code has UB, period. A decent debugging implementation of the  library may *very well* produce errors.

Comment: @KerrekSB: By error, I mean illegal memory access error on the GPU when the GPU kernel which lurks just below the thin vaneer of the thrust API in question. How would a function bounds check an output iterator for sufficient space or valid size? The standard iterator model has no facilities for that, does it?